# Is there a difference between these two sums?

Tags: summation

Let $i,j \in N$ with $i \neq j$, and let $t \in T$.

The sum is written as :
$$\sum_{j \in N \setminus\{i\} }(x_{i,j,t} + x_{j,i,t}) = 2 \qquad \forall i \in N, t \in T$$

Would this be the same as writing:

$$\sum_{t \in T}\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{j \in N \setminus\{i\}} (x_{i,j,t} + x_{j,i,t}) = 2 $$

If not, is there a way to express the first sum without specifying $\;\forall i \in N, t \in T$ and only using sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j \in N \setminus\{i\} }(x_{i,j,t} + x_{j,i,t}) &= 2 \qquad\qquad \forall i \in N, t \in T\tag{1}\\
\sum_{t \in T}\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{j \in N \setminus\{i\}} (x_{i,j,t} + x_{j,i,t}) &= 2\tag{2}
\end{align*}

> - In (1) we have a *system of equations*. For each pair $(i,t)\in N\times T$ we consider the equation
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{j \in N \setminus\{i\} }(x_{i,j,t} + x_{j,i,t})=2
>   \end{align*}
> - In (2) we have a *single equation*:
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{t \in T}\sum_{i \in N} \sum_{j \in N \setminus\{i\}} (x_{i,j,t} + x_{j,i,t}) = 2
>   \end{align*}
>   where we take the sum in (1) and sum it up over all $t\in T$ and $i\in n$.

Note if $N$ and $T$ are finite, we can sum up all equations of (1) and get
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{t \in T}\sum_{i \in N}\sum_{j \in N \setminus\{i\} }(x_{i,j,t} + x_{j,i,t})=2|N| |T|}
\end{align*}

Comment: Ah, I see now. And, if we were to sum each of the equations in (1) with each other, we would end up with (2) right?

Comment: @mathplzfun: We would *nearly* end up with (2). In fact we end up with the last line given in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry I didn't see that. that makes sense!

Comment: @mathplzfun: Everything's fine. Good to see the answer is useful. :-)